# change Color of one word in a preference summary

Tags: android, colors, preferences

Does anyone know how to do this? For me, I would try the usual Html or Spannable that everyone recommends on SOF.However,nothing changes - the preference color stays light gray (I am on android 4.2), unless  I try coloring the ENTIRE  message - then it works. But I just want a single word in the middle of the sentence to be colored - not the whole thing. The rest should be gray (or whatever the default is on my android).

Comment: As you said "I would try the usual Html or Spannable that everyone recommends on SOF.However,nothing changes", can you post your code so people can take a look at it and fix that.

Comment: Post the code so that we know what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

OK, the issue was that I was supposed to wrap the entire text in Html.fromHtml method. Not  just the portion with text I was coloring.